# Cite a particular author when there are multiple authors - how to?

Tags: biblatex, citing

It may happen for some publications, one author among a group of authors are more important than others. Let us say, that author may be more popular or has contributed the most :)

I have official .bib files that are automatically compiled from science magazines. Therefore, there is no chance to modify them.

Here is an example:

```
@article{Williams:2009:RIV:1498765.1498785,
 author = {Williams, Samuel and Waterman, Andrew and Patterson, David},
 title = {Roofline: An Insightful Visual Performance Model for Multicore Architectures},
 //truncated
}
```

Now, in this bibliography, `Patterson` is the the most popular person. When I want to `\citeauthors`, I actually want to have `Patterson et al`. to be printed, instead of `Williams et al`.

`Patterson` is in the third position in this author list.

Is there a way to actually do something like `\citeauthor{ref_code}[index]` where I want to pick the author I want while citing the group?

I use `biblatex` with the `bibtex8` backend.

Comment: I think this goes against all established conventions. In (pure) mathematics the most common convention is that all authors are equal. In fields where not all authors are equal the first author is the "most important" and this is what `\cite` et al will print. There may be a case sometimes to refer to the "senior author" (i.e. the last one, as in some fields this is used for the author who directed or funded the project), in some fields but to refer to author three just because they are more "popular" seems wrong to me.

Comment: Usually only the "first author" has special significance (if any): it doesn't matter who the coolest or most popular or tallest (etc.) person is.

Comment: Well, Andrew, you have a very valid point indeed. However, for some reasons, the third guy is the one known for a particular theory that is very popular in my context. That said, I want to make it easier for my readers to establish the link to the particular context by stating `Patterson et al.` I am sure there must be a Latex trick for that. Any help would be much appreciated (let's put aside the conventions for now :))

Comment: As long as you cite the pieces in a generally acceptable way and get the references right (in particular, the ordering of authors' names is the same as in the actual pieces), any further knowledge you wish to impart about who the most significant authors may have been should be conveyed, if at all, somewhere in a footnote -- but not in the citation callout itself.

Comment: I agree with @Mico, although we are addressing stylistic matters outside the scope of this site. Tell the story you want to about Patterson in the text, but the point of the *citation* is to enable the reader to find the correct source, which will be indexed under Williams. For example: "Patterson first began to develop his famous theory as a collaborator on X project (\cite{williams:2009})."

Comment: Not relevant to the technical detail, but in some areas it's not the first author who is most significant. In chemistry one or more carry a star as the 'corresponding' author(s): those are the important ones, and usually if there is just one they come _last_ in the list. That's usually handled in the text by putting 'BigName and coworkers [X] ...', but that I know of there is no pre-built way to achieve that. I guess this should be doable, but I've never really worried about it as it seems easier to do by hand. (Chemistry uses numerical citations so the link to the paper is separate).

Comment: You could use the `shortname` field with the "preferred" sorting (like this `shortauthor = {Patterson, David and Williams, Samuel and Waterman, Andrew}`): You will then get "Patterson et al." in a citation (and with `\citeauthor` - if `maxcitenames`/`maxnames` is set appropriately). No-one will be able to find the citation in a author-year/title style bibliography though - with a `numeric` style that will not be that much of a problem.

Comment: Ahh, I see, you don't want to change the `.bib` file. In that case you could define a new command that prints only the n-th name in the author list (and adds an "et al." if need be), but then you would need to know the position of the "preferred" author in the author list - I don't think that is more practicable then just writing Patterson in your document, especially since you are not citing the list of authors as such, but just mentioning a name that happens to be on that list. (Let me know if you're interested in that though.)

Comment: @moewe, thank you. Writing a new command would be one way to go and I was expecting I could find some help here with this regard. Well, I hope that I am not the only one with such a request whereby a solution could help many people too :)

Comment: OK, if you want a new macro, you need to be more specific about what exactly you want. What cite/bib style are you using? Do you only want a new `\citeauthor` command, or a new `\cite`, `\textcite` as well?